# Как обьеденить Responsive Accordion Tabs(Foundation) + slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js, foundation

Есть Responsive Accordion Tabs от Foundation, нужно сделать табы в виде карусели.

ПРоблемы начинаются в адаптиве, при уменьшении экрана Responsive Accordion Tabs не срабататывает, табы не становятся аккордеоном. slick отключаю через настройки плагина. Если перезагрузить страницу, то изначально все нормально. Но, после увеличения пропадает контент табов и плагин до конца не отрабатывает при трансформации с аккордиона в табы.

Как исправить эти баги?

```js
$(document).foundation();
enquire.register("screen and (min-width:640px)", {

  match: function() {
    $('.js-tabs-slider').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      nextArrow: '.js-next-arrow',
      prevArrow: '.js-prev-arrow',
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true
        }
      }, {
        breakpoint: 640,
        settings: "unslick"
      }]
    });
  },
});
```

```css
.tabs-nav {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tabs {
  width: 80%;
  flex-basis: 80%;
}

.slider-arrow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  .slider-arrow:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
  .slider-arrow{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .slider-arrow__prev {
    left: 10px;
  }
 .slider-arrow__next {
    right: 10px;
  }
  .slider-arrow.slick-disabled {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

.tabs-slider .slider-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/enquire.js/2.1.6/enquire.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>


<div class="grid-x">
  <div class="cell medium-6 medium-offset-3">

    <div class="tabs-nav">
      <button type="button" class="js-prev-arrow slider-arrow slider-arrow__prev">
          <p>Prev</p>
        </button>
      <ul class="tabs js-tabs-slider" data-responsive-accordion-tabs="tabs small-accordion medium-tabs" id="example-tabs">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active">
          <a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
          <a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
          <a href="#panel3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
          <a href="#panel4">Tab 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
          <a href="#panel5">Tab 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
          <a href="#panel6">Tab 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="js-next-arrow slider-arrow  slider-arrow__next">
          <p>next</p>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
      <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
        <p>one</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed at, nam, adipisci quod fuga, laboriosam laudantium aliquam dolor ullam ab ad fugiat? Placeat est culpa alias similique modi inventore accusamus?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
        <p>two</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed at, nam, adipisci quod fuga, laboriosam laudantium aliquam dolor ullam ab ad fugiat? Placeat est culpa alias similique modi inventore accusamus?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel3">
        <p>three</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed at, nam, adipisci quod fuga, laboriosam laudantium aliquam dolor ullam ab ad fugiat? Placeat est culpa alias similique modi inventore accusamus?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel4">
        <p>four</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed at, nam, adipisci quod fuga, laboriosam laudantium aliquam dolor ullam ab ad fugiat? Placeat est culpa alias similique modi inventore accusamus?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel5">
        <p>five</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed at, nam, adipisci quod fuga, laboriosam laudantium aliquam dolor ullam ab ad fugiat? Placeat est culpa alias similique modi inventore accusamus?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel6">
        <p>six</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed at, nam, adipisci quod fuga, laboriosam laudantium aliquam dolor ullam ab ad fugiat? Placeat est culpa alias similique modi inventore accusamus?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```